# Android: FileInputStream reading old file

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I am storing my file in /data directory.

```
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/logfile.txt");
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) 
            {...}
```

After I change my file and upload it to the device using adb and run the app, the app still continues to read the unchanged file from somewhere. But when I start to debug to see whats happening, its reading the modified file.
I am not sure if its caching it somewhere.

Please help.

Comment: Are you closing the InputStream ?

Comment: yes... I am closing it.